# Variable is not updating despite having good @Query

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to update one variable for user.

Method:

```
    fun blockUser(username: String): Boolean {
            val user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username)
    
            if (user == null) {
                throw UsernameNotFoundException("User not found by username: $username")
            } else {
                userRepository.blockUser(username)
            }
            val justToCheckIfUserIsUpdated = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username) //to be removed
            return true
        }
```

Query

```
   @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update UserEntity c set c.isBlocked = TRUE WHERE c.username = :username")
    fun blockUser(@Param("username") username: String)
```

Test:

```
 @Test
    fun `should block user when user exists`() {
        //given
        val userEntity = UserEntity(
                username = "user",
                phoneNumber = "500200300",
                isBlocked = false,
                email = "kupaa@wp.pl"
        )

        val userService = UserService(userDetailsRepository, userRepository, passwordEncoder)

        userRepository.save(userEntity);

        //when
        userService.blockUser(userEntity.username);

        //then
        val blockedUser = userRepository.findUserByUsername(userEntity.username);
        assertThat(blockedUser!!.isBlocked).isTrue()
    }
```

While debugging you can see that `isblocked` is always true despite I updated it to true value.
Test ends with:

```
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

What I do wrong? I'm really confused.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you do updates using JPQL, the updates go directly to the database. Hibernate doesn't magically update corresponding entities in the persistence context (the first level cache).

This `userRepository.findUserByUsername(username)` should get a user from the database (without the cache). But if you have a `query cache` enabled, the result can be loaded from the cache. You need to enable SQL logging and check the logs for that.

Also keep in mind that `@Transactional` above `blockUser()` method does nothing because spring boot creates a transaction for each test method. It doesn't mean that you have to remove `@Transactional` of course.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you write a bit clearer? What should I do to make this test work? Btw. I didnt add `@Transactional` for test method ;)

Comment: @papakakaka You need to check SQL logs and investigate why data was not saved to database or got from a cahe. `@Transactional` was added by Spring Boot implicitly.